# Express and ejs

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs, web-development-server

I've recently started learning EJS and Express.

Here is my app.js file :

```
   let app = express();
   
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   
   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.render('index');
   });
   app.get('/fallinlovewith/:thing',(req,res)=>{
       var name = req.params.thing;
    res.render('love',{name:name});
   });
   app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

And here are my index.ejs and love.ejs files :
index.ejs :

```
<h1>This is succesful !</h1>
```

love.ejs :

```
<h1>You fell in love with :</h1>
<p>This is from love.ejs folder</p>
```

My code is able to render index.ejs file but not love.ejs .
love.ejs shows the following text instead of the normal heading and paragraph.
[This is what is being displayed at http://localhost:3000/fallinlovewith/dipti](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6llZ.png)
I don't know what these "question mark" symbols denote.
I'm stuck here . Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the language and the charset in the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    ...
```